# string encode / decode

Tags: python, encoding

'=?KOI8-R?B?W1JFUS0wMDI1NDEtNDc5NzddIO/h7yAi89TSz8rGwdLGz9IiIDs=?=\r\n\t=?KOI8-R?B?Ry43MjkgKDEwKQ==?='

How can I convert this into something readable ? 
Thanks !

Comment: Related: [email header decoding UTF-8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331351/python-email-header-decoding-utf-8)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
>>> email.header.decode_header('=?KOI8-R?B?W1JFUS0wMDI1NDEtNDc5NzddIO/h7yAi89TSz8rGwdLGz9IiIDs=?=\r\n\t=?KOI8-R?B?Ry43MjkgKDEwKQ==?=')
[('[REQ-002541-47977] \xef\xe1\xef "\xf3\xd4\xd2\xcf\xca\xc6\xc1\xd2\xc6\xcf\xd2" ;G.729 (10)', 'koi8-r')]
>>> print '[REQ-002541-47977] \xef\xe1\xef "\xf3\xd4\xd2\xcf\xca\xc6\xc1\xd2\xc6\xcf\xd2" ;G.729 (10)'.decode('koi8-r')
[REQ-002541-47977] ОАО "Стройфарфор" ;G.729 (10)
```

Comment: http://translate.google.com/translate_t?hl=&ie=UTF-8&text=%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%84%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80&sl=ru&tl=en# ;)

Comment: It's a compound of the Russian words for 'build' and 'porcelain'. Presumably the name of a company that makes bathroom fittings.

Answer (score 3):

This is encoded-word encoding as specified in [RFC 2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047).

The [`email` package](http://docs.python.org/library/email.header.html) should be able to deal with this format.