# How convert email subject from "?UTF-8?...?=" to readable string?

Tags: python, utf-8, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [string encode / decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896194/string-encode-decode)

Now the subject looks like:
=?UTF-8?B?0J/RgNC+0LLQtdGA0LrQsA==?=

Comment: Out of close votes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896194/string-encode-decode

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The part between `=?UTF-8?B?` and `?=` is a base64-encoded string. Extract that part, and then decode it.

```
import base64

#My buggy SSH account needs this to write unicode output, you hopefully won't
import sys
import codecs
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf-8')(sys.stdout)


encoded = '=?UTF-8?B?0J/RgNC+0LLQtdGA0LrQsA==?='
prefix = '=?UTF-8?B?'
suffix = '?='

#extract the data part of the string
middle = encoded[len(prefix):len(encoded)-len(suffix)]
print "Middle: %s" % middle

#decode the bytes
decoded = base64.b64decode(middle)
#decode the utf-8
decoded = unicode(decoded, 'utf8')

print "Decoded: %s" % decoded
```

Output:

```
Middle: 0J/RgNC+0LLQtdGA0LrQsA==
Decoded: Проверка
```

Comment: So much work to replace 2 lines of correct code...

Comment: Yes, using `email.header.decode_header` seem like a better start, instead of my substring mess. I still explained what was going on though, and how to convert the result from decode_header to a unicode string.

Comment: What standard would this UTF-8 subjects be based on?

Answer (score 11):

Maybe you can use decode_header function: http://docs.python.org/library/email.header.html#email.header.decode_header

Comment: Thanks for replying, but result is not good: [('\xd0\x9f\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0', 'utf-8')]

Comment: You can convert that result into a unicode string, by using `unicode(*result[0])`.